# CRiSP editor open source equivalent?

Tags: open-source, editor

I've recently discovered the [CRiSP editor](http://www.crisp.com/) from one of my clients and was very impressed by its versatility.  Does anyone know of an open source implementation?  I've only found commercial versions by googling. As for what features crisp has that I haven't seen in other editors is the facility with which it handles multiple windows, ability to edit files on multiple hosts in the same session and integration with the shell.  For a full list of features please check the crisp editor link on the main page.

Comment: Many people in you audiance have never used this thing, and "versatility" is a pretty imprecise thing to be impressed with. Emacs is "versatile". Can you say something more about what it does that you like?

Comment: @dmckee thats why the link is there.....repeating whats already very well documented is tedious

Comment: I followed the link. It says it will work on lots of file types and languages. Fine. Emacs does that. Or is there a particular set of behaviors you want?

Comment: edited the question to point out the unique features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

In particular you are probably interested in

- [tramp mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/)
- [shell mode](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/docs/emacs/emacs_408.html)
- the `shell-command` command (typically bound to `M-!`), and related tools. Use `C-h f shell-command` to get help.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt an open source equivalent of CRiSP. CRiSP was originally based on an MSDOS editor called BRIEF, but over the years, it has incorporated many of the desirable features of other editors (Visual Studio, Eclipse, Emacs). It aims to be efficient and proficient for editing a wide variety of files.

Emacs did have a crisp-mode macro added to it, but its somewhat crude.

If anyone is interested in a free copy of CRiSP, I would be happy to give out some free licenses in response for feedback.

(Apologies if this sounds like an advert, but I would rather people use and contribute to the product, rather than ignore it simply because it is a commercial one).

Comment: I'd like to take you up on your free offer for editing the headers of vmdk files. Cheers